# How to ensure that the object ID has not been modified by an attacker user inside my asp.net mvc web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security

I have two objects with a one-to-many relation (`LabTest & LabTestDetail`). When i want to add a new `LabTestDetail` object  i pass the `LabTest ID` (the parent ID)  to the `LabTestDetail Create action method` in an `Ajax.actionlink` as follow

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("+ Add New Lab Test Detail",
      "Create", "LabTestDetail",
      new { labtestid = Model.LabTestID },

new AjaxOptions
{

    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "Get",
    UpdateTargetId = "replace",
    LoadingElementId = "progress"
})
```

The `LabTestDetail` `Create Action method` looks as follow;  where i store the value of the `labtestid`  in a `viewbag` :-

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Doctor")]

public ActionResult Create(int labtestid)
            {
                ViewBag.labtestid = labtestid;
                LabTestDetail ltr = new LabTestDetail();
                return PartialView("_Create", ltr);
            }
```

Then on the `create view` i store the value of the `Viewbag` on a `hidden html field` as follow:-

```
<input type= "hidden" name = "labtestid" value = @ViewBag.labtestid />
```

Finally the `LabTestDetail` `Post Create action` method look as follow:-

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Doctor")]    
[HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Create(LabTestDetail ltr, int labtestid)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        ltr.LabTestID = labtestid;
                        repository.AddLabTestDetail(ltr);
                        repository.Save();
                        return PartialView("_datails", ltr);
                    }
                }
    //code goes here
```

The above works fine for me when i test it ,,, **but my big concern is how i can make sure that the value of the `labtestid` has not been modified by an attacker during the following actions**:-

1. when i pass the `labtestid` value from the `ajax.action link` to the `create action method`
2. when i pass the `labtestid` value as a view bag
3. and finally when i assign the `labtestid` value to a `html hidden field`.

Best Regards
Thanks in advance for any help.
BR

Answer (score 0):

If you use authentication and only authenticated users could perform those operations, inside the action that is supposed to perform the update you could verify if the currently authenticated user (`User.Identity.Name`) is the owner of the lab test. For this to work it means that you need to associate those lab test ids with users.

Comment: Yes I am using the [Authorize(Roles = "Doctor")] before that action methods “i update my original code” , but any doctor can add LabTestDetails regardless of weather he is the owner of the LabTest object or not. But my concern is that if my application allows a professional attacker to modify the ID value, then this might cause security problems i might be unaware of .. So I want to prevent an attacker from being able to modify the ID just to provide a new security layer to my application, so is there a way to do this??